# How to configure an external-secrets.io PushSecret with a cert-manager secret?

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I'm trying to configure a `PushSecret` to push a cert-manager tls cert secret to Hashicorp Vault.

This is my PushSecret manifest

```yaml
---
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1alpha1
kind: PushSecret
metadata:
  name: example-pushsecret # Customisable
  namespace: example # Same of the SecretStores
spec:
  deletionPolicy: Delete # the provider' secret will be deleted if the PushSecret is deleted
  refreshInterval: 10s # Refresh interval for which push secret will reconcile
  secretStoreRefs: # A list of secret stores to push secrets to
    - name: secretstore-example
      kind: SecretStore
  selector:
    secret:
      name: example-client-cert-streaming # Source Kubernetes secret to be pushed
  data:
    - match:
        remoteRef:
          remoteKey: /example/example-client-cert-streaming # Remote reference (where the secret is going to be pushed)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
  Type     Reason   Age                 From        Message
  ----     ------   ----                ----        -------
  Warning  Errored  52s (x9 over 29m)   pushsecret  set secret failed: could not write remote ref  to target secretstore secretstore-example: error unmarshalling vault secret: unexpected end of JSON input
```

I'm not sure I understand why it is trying to unmarshall the vault secret.  Am I doing something wrong here?